# MySQL - aggregate totals of each type of value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a table called portal events which stores an event on a website - when it happens, and its type, either 'l', 'w' or 'a'.

I'm trying to get the totals of each type for the last 6 months (ignoring any months when an event didn't happen), i.e. so I'd end up with something like:

```
date_identifier    total_l    total_a    total_w
2017-07            5          4          10
2017-08            8          2          13
...etc
```

Here's my query. The problem is it's giving me the same value (the overall total) for every row, not the total specific to that event type.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT SUBSTRING(pe.date, 1, 7) AS date_identifier,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pe_l.id) AS total_l,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pe_w.id) AS total_w,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pe_a.id) AS total_a
FROM 4diboxnnnqt pe
LEFT JOIN 4diboxnnnqt pe_l ON pe_l.user = pe.user && pe_l.type = "l"
LEFT JOIN 4diboxnnnqt pe_a ON pe_a.user = pe.user && pe_a.type = "a"
LEFT JOIN 4diboxnnnqt pe_w ON pe_w.user = pe.user && pe_w.type = "w"
WHERE
    pe.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) &&
    pe.user IN (SELECT user FROM 2oz5a186fle ue JOIN jh4iw0ii196 pc ON ue.user_type IN ("s", "ds") && pc.id = ue.promo && pc.parent_teacher_code = 'nvcdig8isly')
GROUP BY date_identifier
```

Gives me, for example:

```
date_identifier    total_l    total_a    total_w
2017-07            8          2          13
2017-08            8          2          13
2017-09            8          2          13
2017-10            8          2          13
2017-11            8          2          13
2017-12            8          2          13
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong to get this duplication, rather than the month-by-month totals? I thought the `GROUP_BY` would nail this.

My rationale behind the query structure was to pull date from the events table to get the unique months when an event of ANY type happened, then join to itself, once per type, to get the differentiated totals. Bad logic?

(P.S. I know I can do this with sub-queries, but I assumed they'd be slower...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arggh.  I think you just need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT LEFT(pe.date, 7) AS date_identifier,
       SUM(pe.type = 'l') AS total_l,
       SUM(pe.type = 'w') AS total_w,
       SUM(pe.type = 'a') AS total_a
FROM 4diboxnnnqt pe
WHERE pe.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND
      pe.user IN (SELECT user
                  FROM 2oz5a186fle ue JOIN
                       jh4iw0ii196 pc
                       ON ue.user_type IN ('s', 'ds') AND
                          pc.id = ue.promo AND
                          pc.parent_teacher_code = 'nvcdig8isly'
                 )
GROUP BY date_identifier;
```

Notes:

- The ANSI standard for the boolean and is `AND`, not `&&`.
- The ANSI standard for quotes strings uses a single quote, not a double quote.
- Without the `JOIN`s, I don't think `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you explain why `SUM` produces the right results yet `COUNT` produces the same value for each type? For example, say there were 1 of type 'l' for February and 0 of the other two types, with `COUNT` I end up with total_l=1, total_a=1, total_w=1, i.e. the grand total for all types each time. With `SUM` it works, for some reason.

Comment: @Utkanos . . . It has to do with all the joins, not `sum()` versus `count()`.

Comment: Yeap, sure, but you also changed `count` to `sum`. I'm curious about that. I mean, I know what they both do, but I would have thought I was counting here, not summing.

Comment: @Utkanos . . . You want conditional aggregation.  This is the right way to count the values.  I have to think to hard to figure out what your query is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a count case or sum case.

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pe.date, 1, 7) AS date_identifier,
    sum(case when pe.type = "l" then 1 else 0 end ) AS total_l,
    sum(case when pe.type = "w" then 1 else 0 end ) AS total_w,
    sum(case when pe.type = "a" then 1 else 0 end ) AS total_a
FROM 4diboxnnnqt pe
WHERE 
...
group by date_identifier;

Comment: Thank you. The other answer was the one I went to first and helped, but +1 for your help too.